# Durandal activationData nested in widget

Tags: knockout.js, widget, durandal

I'm creating a Durandal widget and its works fine. My question is about activationData. It seems to be infinitely nested and I have no idea why.

If inspect the `settings` argument passed inside `activate` and drill down to `activationData`, the object keeps being nested within itself. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 'infinitely nested' it is simply referencing each other in what is called a circular reference in JavaScript.  As long as you don't try to `toJSON()` it you should be fine, it's common practice.

Take a parent / child relationship for example -

```
Parent
  - Child

Child
  - Parent
```

A parent has a child which also has a parent.  No biggie.